# Load image files with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

I was wondering if it's possible to load an image 
(from a form with an < input type="file" /> or something else like drag-and-drop area) only with AJAX ?

I ask this question because everyone have answered : "No it's definitely impossible due to a security problem. A web browser can't access file system".

So how this website do : [Mothereffing Animated Gif](http://mothereffinganimatedgif.com/) ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: There are several jquery plugins that do that, here is a list with some: http://creativefan.com/10-ajax-jquery-file-uploaders/ By the way, I think the trick is doing the uploads in a hidden iframe.

Comment: definitely possible as I've coded it before. Currently trying to find the document it's in..

Comment: @jeroen you dont need an iframe. Theres a way to do it using a temporary file.

Comment: The sad truth, is that the website you linked to does not work dragging from Thunar into Firefox13.

Comment: By "load" do you mean "upload"? Because if you are trying to view a file selected in a file input, I can't see where the server commutation provided by Ajax would be involved.

Comment: @CoreyRS I think that depends on the browser support you wish to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20drag%20and%20drop%20file) "ajax drag and drop file", and the first result is [this](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Short answer: yes, it's very much possible.
You should consider, though, that drag and dropping doesn't work perfectly on every browser/enviroment, so you should still keep an alternate button just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Mothereffing Animated Gif is using Backbone and this [script](http://mothereffinganimatedgif.com/assets/js/models.js) to convert the image to base64 data url.